# LightGBM: Are negative values (ie. missing values) in categorical features treated as a separate category?

Tags: python, categories, decision-tree, categorical-data, lightgbm

Based on LightGBM's documentation in the link below, the parameter `categorical_feature` (for categorical features) states that "All negative values in categorical features will be treated as missing values."

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier

My question is: Are the negative values (ie. missing values) in categorical features treated as a separate category? Or are they just treated as missing values and are not included as a category in the model?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The missing values could join up with the 1's or 0's in your one-hot encoded feature columns depending on which split is best for the model performance.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. However, according to this documentation (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advanced-Topics.html), it states "LightGBM offers good accuracy with integer-encoded categorical features. LightGBM applies Fisher (1958) to find the optimal split over categories as described here. This often performs better than one-hot encoding." It says lightGBM performs better than the one-hot encoding, so I don't think any one-hot encoding is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way :) the nans will be grouped in a way that minimizes error, not discarded

Comment: Thanks. So in some ways, they are treated as a separate group and they may be grouped together with other categories in the categorical variable.